# Nginx proxy everything under a path to a specific file on a remote server

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have a rails running at `example.com` behind nginx.  `example.com/foobar` will hit that rails app with the path `/foobar`, which is all well and good.

What I want to add is that `example.com/spa/*` loads a specific file from a remote server (in this case an s3 bucket, but that's not important).

So, I'd want nginx to map things like so:

```
example.com/ -> rails app with path /
example.com/foo -> rails app with path /foo
example.com/bar?what=ever -> rails app with path /bar?what=ever

example.com/spa -> my-bucket.amazonaws.com/index.html
example.com/spa/foo -> my-bucket.amazonaws.com/index.html
example.com/spa/bar?what=ever -> my-bucket.amazonaws.com/index.html
```

The first three examples are easy- that's just

```
location / {
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass http://app_server;
}
```

(with `upstream app_server` defined elsewhere)

The second three example, though, I'm not sure how to do.

TLDR: How do you proxy everything under a specific path to a single file/path on a remote server?

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/rlguog/nginx-as-proxy-for-amazon-s3-public-private-files

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to address the issue I'm going for here.  It's relatively straightforward to proxy a path on my server to a path on s3– `/foo/bar` on my server goes to `/bar` on s3, and `/foo/baz` goes to `/baz` on s3.

What I'm trying to do is proxy all requests under a path on my server to a single file on s3: `/foo/bar` on my server goes to `/a_file` on s3, and `/foo/baz` also goes to `/a_file` on s3.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but if you're only serving a single file, can you just redirect to your bucket? Is this not the intention?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
location ^~ /spa {
    rewrite ^ /index.html break;
    proxy_pass ...;
}
```

The `^~` modifier may not be necessary, unless you have some regular expression locations at the same level. It causes this prefix location to take precedence. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

The `rewrite ... break` causes the modified URI to be processed within the current location block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.